# Best way to save data

Tags: android, storage

The thing is I need to store something like:

```
100 strings
20-30 ints
```

As you can see, it's a pretty large number, and you might say "Use sql"! I would use sql but for me it looks kinda alien. It's a lot of code, and after that I can't find a tutorial that shows you: look, you make a database with tables like this, and then you read it like this, you can also search in it like this...

Can you please give me the best method to save that data? And if you say sql, please give me a tutorial or something that shows me how to do what I said above.

Comment: ?! I don't know,for me it is! Especially if you have to work with all of them!

Comment: you just want to have static 100 strings/20-30 int value, i mean you want to include as a static values inside your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQl, look at ORMLite, which will let you store objects in the db (http://ormlite.com/).  For 100 strings, if they're basically name/value pairs, just use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html.  Could also use static string resources, as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing ormlite! That's a lot easier than regular sql! And it has great examples! I don't know if I'll use it for this project,but I'm sure I will test it,,and that's what I'm gonna use in my next projects!

Answer (score 2):

I would say you should look into SQLite and try to learn that. But if you really want to stay away from SQL you could use [putStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) to store your strings in SharedPreferences. Now there isn't a thing for putIntSet but you could convert your ints to strings using String.valueOf(myInt) and save it using the same [putStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29). I would like to be clear though, I think that a database is the way to go on this but this method should work for you.